# how to select all FK for a product in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How can i list all the foreign keys of each product ?
The question is :-

Write a SELECT statement that lists the name, product number, and all the foreign keys of each product from the Production.Product table.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you give an example of the output?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[sql]` and `[server]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[sql-server]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN's to join related tables, and select values only from them. There is no magical keywords like "select data from all tables that are foreign to this" in SQL. You can only manually join your tables.

Comment: Sure there is, you can use dynamic TSQL to fetch all the FK fields in a table, or referencing said table, and then build a SQL to return all those rows. It's just that it's probably not what the OP is really looking for. :)